# Multiple definitions of main; Only have one main for project

Tags: c, program-entry-point

My program outputs that there are multiple definitions of main. Not sure what's going on, my project has one main function. Any help will be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int identical(int a[], int b[], unsigned int len){
    int counter = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len; i++){
        if(a[i] == b[i]){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter == len){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(){
    int x[3] = {1,1};
    int y[3] = {1,2};
    printf("%d\n", identical(x, y, 2));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you compile it?

Comment: Is `main` defined in a header file, or in a .c file that is (for some reason) included in another?

Comment: Please include the output from your compiler.

Comment: the problem is not in the file but in the way your compile and finaly link

Comment: Are you sure, did you make new project/folder for your solution?

Comment: Your program compiles and runs without error for me.

Comment: `for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len; i++)` why is `i` initialized `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`? Arrays are **zero** based in C. You are only comparing the 2nd and 3rd elements (the 3rd being initialized to zero by default since it was not explicitly initialized when you did, e.g. `int x[3] = {1,1};`)

Answer (score 1):

Yea, this shouldn't be happening. If you are using gcc try compiling it with `cc filename.c -o filename` and then run it with `./filename`.

If that doesn't work then try and change the directory or folder it's in.

The final solution I could think of is copying the whole code into a new file and saving that under a different name.